# How to update the delegated permissions given from a user to a microsoft graph application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The main problem is that I have a microsoft application created in :
https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList
this application have this delegated permissions: 
claendars.Read, contacts.read, profile and people.read; when a user log in my application it ask the user to confer this permissions and everything fine, but if I want to update the permissions (for example add task.read), even if I add them to the application delegated permission list, in the next log in of the user the app don't ask the user to update the permissions and the new permissions are never granted.
there is any way to update the permissions given by de user to the app?

Comment: Try to clear the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you redirect the user to the login site to get the auth code, make sure you update the url to include the updated permissions in the *scope* query parameter

```
// Line breaks for legibility only

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read%20task.read
&state=12345
```